# Throwing away certain values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, valueerror

So I have an array (x) with 20 different values, and I want to get rid of all the numbers that are greater than 10. I tried this:

```
while x <= 10:
    x2 = x
```

but this was returned: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" And I don't know how to use those functions. Any suggestions on a better way to get rid of values greater than 10 in my array?

Comment: Please update your question with a examples of the array before and after this transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` array indexing to filter array values.  For example,

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
x_2 = x[x < 3]
```

where x_2 will return:

> array([1, 2])

You should be able to adapt this example to your use case.